# Replacing the words from a string using php

Tags: php

I am trying to replace the words in a string using php.
Here i want to replace the words "test php" and "java test" with "new program" and "test program" from the $replacearray array.
Note:Here i need to search the words in the string using $searchstring array if matching found it should replace with the $replacearray

The output should be This is new program and test program

Here if my searchstring contains numbers also i want to explode it and seperate the numbers and strings, and want to replace the $string with the exploded string.Here the delimiter i am using is : in $searchstring

Here is my code

```
 <?php
 $string = "This is test php and java test";
 $searchstring = array('1:test php', '2:java test');
 $replacearray = array('new program', 'test program');

 $replacearraycount = count($replacearray);
 $searchstringcount = count($searchstring);

 for($i = 0; $i < $replacearraycount; $i++) {
     for($i = 0; $i < $searchstringcount; $i++) {
         $string = preg_replace("/".$searchstring[$i]."/", $replacearray[$i], $string, 1);
     }
 }

 echo $string;
 ?>
```

This is what i am trying by exploding the $searchstring

```
 <?php
 $string = "This is test php and java test";
 $searchstring = array('1:test php', '2:java test');
 $replacearray = array('test coding','test program');

 $replacearraycount = count($replacearray);
 $searchstringcount = count($searchstring);

 foreach ($searchstring as &$value) {
 $arrid = array();
 $arrname = array();
 foreach (explode(', ', $value) as $el) {
 $ret = explode(':', $el);
 $arrid[$ret[0]] = $ret[0];
 $arrname[$ret[0]] = $ret[1];
 }
 $valueid = $arrid;
 $name = $arrname;

 $finalsearchstring=array();
 array_push($finalsearchstring,$name);
 }

 for($i = 0; $i < $replacearraycount; $i++) {
 $string = preg_replace("/".$finalsearchstring[$i]."/", $replacearray[$i], $string, 1);
 }

 echo $string;
 ?>
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't get it. What is the question?

Comment: Oh. You've used `$searchstring[i]` and `$searchstring[i]` while it should be `$i` instead of just `i` in both case. Is that a typo in your question?

Answer (score 3):

If I follow your question, you need one for loop not two and your array index should be `$i` not just `i` -

```
for($i = 0; $i < $replacearraycount; $i++) {
  $string = preg_replace("/".$searchstring[$i]."/", $replacearray[$i], $string, 1);
}
```